# How can the path to an executing ruby script be determined from inside another script?

Tags: ruby

I have two ruby scripts: "main.rb" and "sub.rb" in the same directory.

**main.rb**

```
require "./sub.rb"

someMethod
```

**sub.rb**

```
def someMethod
    puts __FILE__
end
```

When the main.rb script is run, the output shows the path to the "sub.rb" file (e.g., .../ruby-examples/get-script-directory/sub.rb). I'm looking for something that I can use in place of the `puts __FILE__` line that will return the path to "main.rb" instead.

This is a simplified example. The real goal here is to be able to put ruby module scripts anywhere and have them reference the directory (via something like File.dirname()) the main executing script is in. For example to write outputs or log files in the main script's directory.

Is there a way to determine the path to the executing ruby script from an included module script?

Comment: File.dirname($0)    http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/variable.html#zero

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Make that an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$0` is the file of the executing script, so you could use:

```
File.dirname($0)
```

http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/variable.html#zero